# Enclosing building models from bottom (Missing GroundFeatures) using FME?

Tags: shapefile, fme-form, intersection, terrain, citygml

I have 3D building model of the city and I would like to export it to proper CityGML model.

I am trying to find out, how to make an intersection of building and terrain in order to make "TerrainIntersectionCurve".

So literally, I am looking for some steps how to make intersection of terrain and building models using FME?

Comment: Would you be able to [edit] your question to give more precise details of what you have done and where you are stuck, please?

Comment: A screenshot of your workspace might help.